# Ways to Create a Number with Sum of Ones and Twos

Tags: algorithm, sum, numbers

I am wondering if there is a way to count the possible ways to sum a number using only ones and twos

For example:

We have the number 10. The number 10 can be summed by:

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1  
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2
2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 
etc...
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Does the order matter? Is 1 + 1 + ... + 1 +  2 different from 2 + 1 + 1  + 1 + ... + 1?

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe of [Intuition behind the base case for counting the number of steps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41338678/572670). The other question asks for intuition about a **specific** solution, which might not be the best or easiest one. This question can be answered by multiple other solutions.

Comment: No, the order doesn't matter. The idea is to count in how many ways a number can be summed using only 1s and 2s. It's a problem that a friend of mine and I  thought about but we couldn't implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of elements does not matter, as the comments explain (i.e. `1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2` is identical to `2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1`), this is simply choosing the number of elements in the summation, which can be anywhere between 5 to 10. Once the number of elements is chosen, you know exactly how many of them have to be 1s and how many of them have to be 2s: For x elements, there are 10-x 2s, and the rest are 1s.

Since there are 6 numbers to choose from, this is the number of ways to create 10.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than going into complex mathematical formulas, I would recommend DP approach.

```
    int arr[N+1]; // Represents no. of ways to produce a number at index 1
    // Like arr[5] is no. of ways to produce number 5
    
    for(int i=0;i<=N;i++) {
      arr[i] = 1; // As all 1s
    }
    
    for(int i=2;i<=N;i++) {
      // if we add 2 now, check for no. of ways i-2 can be made, 
      // add it to current arr[i] value.
      arr[i] += arr[i-2];
    }
    
    cout<< (arr[N]); // print
```

Answer (score 0):

Number of ways to create a number using only ones = `1` 
Number of ways to create a number using at least one two = `floor(n/2)` 
Total = `1 + floor(n/2)`

See `javascript` code snippet below:

```js
let numWays = n => 1 + Math.floor(n/2);

for (let i=1; i<=20; i++)
    console.log("Number of ways to create " + i + " is: " + numWays(i));
```